# python - list operations

Tags: python, list

Given a list of unsorted numbers, I want to find the smallest number larger than N (if any).

In C#, I'd do something like this (checks omitted) :

```
var x = list.Where(i => i > N).Min();
```

What's a short, READABLE way to do this in Python?

Comment: What do *you* mean by "READABLE"?

Comment: @SLott 
"read·a·ble/ˈrēdəbəl/: (2) Easy or enjoyable to read."

What do you mean by "What do you mean by readable?" ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
>>> l = [4, 5, 12, 0, 3, 7]
>>> min(x for x in l if x > 5)
7
```

Answer (score 4):

```
min(x for x in mylist if x > N)
```

Answer (score 3):

Other people have given list comprehension answers. As an alternative `filter` is useful for 'filtering' out elements of a list.

```
min(filter(lambda t: t > N, mylist))
```

Comment: using filter is a little bit slower than using generator expressions

Comment: +1. I've asked this question partly to improve my Python skills, so this answer serves my purpose quite well.

Answer (score 2):

```
x = min(i for i in mylist if i > N)
```